# Used Group Policy to install an x86 version of .NET 4.6.2 on an x64 system and it didn't work at all

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit, group-policy, .net-framework

Not only does is completely not work, but it's proving impossible to uninstall; giving me this message:

[image: [screenshot]]

I've tried installing the 64-bit version over the 32-bit one using another GPO, and that didn't work. I've tried using Microsoft's .NET repair tool, and that didn't work [shocking, really] so I'm kind of grasping at straws here. There doesn't seem to be any kind of force-uninstall utility for me to use and Google searches have so far proven unhelpful. These are Win7 systems.

Any ideas on how to get this software off of the affected workstations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for the edit, I apparently can't directly embed pictures yet with my account.

And can people not just downvote the question because you don't know the answer?

Comment: That's weird. You have more than enough rep. What happens if you the insert image shortcut <ctrl><g> or the Image button?

Comment: I didn't downvote ...

Comment: @DavidPostill It just told me I didn't have the ability yet...

Comment: You only need 10 rep ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can uninstall any program using wmic:

```
wmic product where name="WinZip 15.0" call uninstall /nointeractive
```

Comment: YOU ARE A GOD AMONG MEN. HOW DID I GO MY WHOLE LIFE AND NOT KNOW ABOUT THIS?!